# TabStop property is not working for usercontrol inside the panel

Tags: c#, user-controls, focus, tabstop

I have a usercontrol which is placed inside one panel and some other controls like buttons in another panel. when the usercontrol is active and i move from other controls using tab key, usercontrol gets focus even when the TapStop property for the usercontrol is set to "False".

In another case, when i have the usercontrol placed in the form not inside the panel, usercontrol didnt get focused when moving from other controls using tab key.

Could anyone share me the details why the usercontrol is getting focused when it is only placed inside the panel?

Thanks and Regards,
Amal

Comment: any code would make this more clear...put the code pls.

Comment: myUserControl.TabStop = false;